# How to redirect invalid urls using mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am new in mod_rewrite regular expressions. I have the following lines in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)/ gallery.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^gallery/ gallery.php [L]
```

When I open `http://127.0.0.1/gallery/` everything is OK, but when I open `http://127.0.0.1/gallery/some_string` it opens the same page. How can I force such invalid URL-s to go to my 404 page. I need the second line to be strict - with no extra characters after the last slash and the first rule must continue to work with integer values.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/ gallery.php [L]
```

In this rule the pattern `^gallery/` matches any and all strings that start with "gallery/", including "gallery/some_string". To make it strict, to ensure that it matches only "gallery/" and nothing else, use the $ metacharacter, which signifies the end of the string:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/$ gallery.php [L]
```

(You may want to make the last slash optional by using the ? operator (`RewriteRule ^gallery/?$ gallery.php [L]`) to ensure that http://example.com/gallery also works -- users expect this behaviour, even if it's sloppy.)